# MVC get data from controller to view using AJAX what's wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

i'm trying to get data from controller to view and receiving it with ajax this my action :

```
public JsonResult addtocart(int id)
    {
        var Product = db.Product.SingleOrDefault(c => c.id == id);
        var Cart = new Cart();

        ProductCart pc = new ProductCart()
        {

            Product = Product,
            Cart = Cart

        };
        pc.Cart.added_at = DateTime.Now;

        pc.Cart.product_id = pc.Product.id;
        db.Cart.Add(pc.Cart);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(pc.Product, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

when i press on "add to cart" button for one of the products and i want to add this to a modal contains a table it's class is "myjxT", Here's my ajax :

```
$('.addtocart').click(function () {
        var name = $(".item-name").text();
        var price = $(".item-price").text();
        $.ajax({
            method :'GET',
            url: "/Product/addtocart",
            dataType: JSON,
            cache: false,
            data: { "Name": name, "Price": price },
            success: function (data) {
                var content = "";
                for (var x in data) {
                    content = "<tr><td>" + data[x].Name + "</td><td>" + data[x].Price + "</td></tr>"

                }
                $(".myjxT").html(content);

            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert("something wrong");
            }

        });

    });
```

but it does nothing just when i click to "add to cart "it directs me to this url : "Product/addtocart/35" where 35 is the product id,And the page contains json object of the product :

```
{"Category":{"id":11,"name":"kikii","number_of_products":3},"id":35,"name":"Samsung Galaxy M31","price":8000,"image":"Samsung Galaxy M31.jpg","description":"t is a long established ","CategoryId":11}
```

this is the "add to cart " button which is inside a **foreach** loop:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Add to cart", "addtocart", new { id = item.id }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger addtocart", @style = "width:90px;background-color:rgb(60, 60, 60)" })
```

Comment: share the html, of add to click and form if you have used

Comment: @AhmedSunny check it again,and i don't have a form for add to cart just a button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are receiving an AJAX error is because your parameters in your controller method does not match the parameters you have in your AJAX call.

```
public JsonResult addtocart(int id)

data: { "Name": name, "Price": price },
```

You need to pass the product id in the AJAX call.

e.g.

```
data: { "id": productid },
```